# Redirecting an external link to a new website

Tags: .htaccess

I have a link on a page, for example http://123.456.789/~preview/websites.com and I need this to actually display and redirect to a new address, for example website.com

Can this be done using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

I'm not sure what is the page and what is the link in your question, you're not being very clear. However, take this example:

I have a page /websites.html and on it I link to /websites/example.com which should be redirected to example.com:

```
RewriteRule ^websites/example.com http://example.com/ [R,L]
```

If you would want to redirect all urls in your /websites/ folder to their respective website:

```
RewriteRule ^websites/(.+)\.(.+)$ http://$1.$2/ [R,L]
```

(this would redirect /websites/test.com to http://test.com, /websites/www.del.icio.us to http://www.del.icio.us, etc)